# How to use ABAP boolean in IF condition?

Tags: abap

I know abap has no real boolean type. Instead 'X' and ' ' is used. Up to this time I always used an if-statement that way:

```
IF myObj->is_sth( ) = abap_true.

ENDIF.
```

Now I did something like this:

```
IF myObj->is_sth( ).

ENDIF.
```

And I'm wondering that this seems to work. Return Type is boolean. I'm on Netweaver 7.4. Can I use this without problems? It's like my lovely C# writing :p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [*predicative method call*](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenpredicative_method_calls.htm):

> A predicative method call is a relational expression whose only
>   operand is a functional method call meth( ... ). The result of the
>   relational expression is true if the result of the functional method
>   call is not initial and false if the result of the functional method
>   call is initial. The result of the functional method call (the return
>   value of the called function method) can have any data type. A check
>   is made on the type-friendly initial value.
>
> A predicative method call, like any relational expression, can be a
>   full logical expression or part of a logical expression. This means it
>   can be specified as a condition in control statements and other
>   statements, as an argument in Boolean functions or conditional
>   expressions, or in joins with Boolean operators.

This was [introduced in 7.40 SP08](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abennews-740_sp08-expressions.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_1@1@). Be aware that this only works reliably if the initial value is false and false is the initial value. For instance, IS-H uses a character field where `0` is false and `1` is true - but since the initial value of a character field is a space, that's neither true nor false, so using any method that returns this value will always branch as if the method had returned true...